# DKIM DNS TXT Record Error

Tags: email, dkim, exim, dovecot

I am testing my mail serveur DKIM and SPF settings with Port25 auth test.

SPF is perfect, but my DKIM doesn't work. Here is the error:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
DKIM check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         permerror (key "default._domainkey.pokesharp.com" doesn't exist)
ID(s) verified: 
Canonicalized Headers:
message-id:<4b811ef394a3840c888aaf70e625190c@pokesharp.com>'0D''0A'
subject:123'0D''0A'
to:check-auth@verifier.port25.com'0D''0A'
from:admin@pokesharp.com'0D''0A'
date:Mon,'20'12'20'Aug'20'2013'20'10:38:04'20'-0400'0D''0A'
mime-version:1.0'0D''0A'
dkim-signature:v=1;'20'a=rsa-sha256;'20'q=dns/txt;'20'c=relaxed/relaxed;'20'd=pokesharp.com;'20's=default;'20'h=Message-ID:Subject:To:From:Date:MIME-Version;'20'bh=47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=;'20'b=;

Canonicalized Body:

DNS record(s):
    default._domainkey.pokesharp.com. TXT (NXDOMAIN)

NOTE: DKIM checking has been performed based on the latest DKIM specs
(RFC 4871 or draft-ietf-dkim-base-10) and verification may fail for
older versions.  If you are using Port25's PowerMTA, you need to use
version 3.2r11 or later to get a compatible version of DKIM.
```

Although, in my DNS, I do have "default._domainkey" IN TXT 14400 with value:

`"v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCjUEWGRzEyKE0GcoICtp4bAKhrIjG8zubaDBV8MJSEO49nJHPk8zTJNFYmFBaMX0GVwxstam3C231TedkiRBk5RQ32lOqiaHW/PGpYqGrdE95arh8floBinkcVCqwnodUMBizDLh0rZvdOf+lElQAf0nBFL0X2EhGDC4IlEYpu7QIDAQAB;"`

I don't quite understand why it doesn't see it. (I'm using cPanel/WHM)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that it was just propagation delays?  If I query your DNS now, I get your DKIM public key (see below).  Are you still getting the same results from the port25 verifier?

```
mti2935@basement:~$ nslookup -q=TXT default._domainkey.pokesharp.com
Server:         75.75.75.75
Address:        75.75.75.75#53

Non-authoritative answer:
default._domainkey.pokesharp.com        text = "v=DKIM1\; k=rsa\; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCjUEWGRzEyKE0GcoICtp4bAKhrIjG8zubaDBV8MJSEO49nJHPk8zTJNFYmFBaMX0GVwxstam3C231TedkiRBk5RQ32lOqiaHW/PGpYqGrdE95arh8floBinkcVCqwnodUMBizDLh0rZvdOf+lElQAf0nBFL0X2EhGDC4IlEYpu7QIDAQAB\;"

Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that you should NEVER change a DKIM selector in DNS. Instead you create a new selector and then configure all of your servers to use that new selector, and leave the old selector in DNS for some period of time (days, weeks, months, you set the policy for how long it hangs around).